# Mysql insert large number of rows or save array as string field

Tags: mysql

I have two tables "bundles" and "pages2bundles". Each item in the "bundles" table is a reference to a document in a third table called "documents".

Each document reference in "documents" is unique. "bundles" may contain duplicate references from the "documents" table.

I allow users to create and save "bundles" to he database. These can be created following a search of the "documents" table in which case all that needs to be done is to save the document reference to the "bundles" table. Each bundle may run to several thousand document references.

There is also a table "texts" which contains the OCR text from each document. My users can create bundles by searching the "texts" table. These searches need to retain the id of both the document and the individual page nos returned by the search. Saving these bundles could easily result in the need to insert upwards of 100,000 page references into "pages2bundles".

I haven't gone live with this yet. I have tested it myself with upwards of 100,000 pages and both insertion times and reloading of the bundle are reasonable. Both tables have all necessary fields indexed.

However, there could be a lot of these bundles being created, which presumably would eventually have a hit on performance.

I was wondering if there was any good reason why I should not just dispose of "pages2bundles" and instead store the page no references for each document in "bundles" as a simple csv test array. I have no need (as far as I can so far see) to search for page no references in "pages2bundles". And I would assume this would improve server performance by passing the burden of dealing with the array to the client.

I would welcome any views as to pros and cons of dealing with the page refs as a text array.

Comment: Word of advice - when you start dealing with performance and potential issues, **always** have hardware specs ready.  You can't be making software and expecting that it works fast on any device you install it at. Min-maxing with junction tables and without them is most likely meaningless in the grand scheme, but if you don't need something and won't need it at all - don't use it and don't add complexity. Make up a number that you want to satisfy, performance-wise, allocate budget for hardware and work towards meeting the performance goal. It won't work otherwise.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I won't have hardware specs available. The app will be used by any number of people and I will not necessarily know what hardware they are using so it is more of a general question as to the advisability of using a text array field in the bundles table rather than creating a potentially gargantuan bundle_pages table. Any views?

Comment: In that case, whatever approach you come up with here - you can't guarantee performance. You need to be able to control I/O to achieve a lot of writes and even if you create optimal data model / code - you still depend on hardware, which is why I wrote the paragraph about it. In your case, I'd go with the data model that **you** find easy and maintainable, because if you can't guarantee hardware and I/O control, whatever you do with data model will have modest impact on performance, at most.

Comment: OK. Thanks. But in principle am I right in thinking there is nothing fundamentally wrong in using a text field which contains a csv array of pages nos as opposed to a table with a row for each of those page nos?

Comment: If you are not performing searches on that textual data and if you only need the contents of that text, without performing any type of relational operation on it - I see no reason why you would be wrong, so yes, you're correct.